# Which second order kernel is symmetric, has bounded support and satisfy $\int x^2 k(x)dx=1$?

Tags: kernel-smoothing, moments, symmetry

Suppose $k(\cdot)$ is a univariate kernel function of order 2 in the sense that $\int x k(x)dx=0$, and $\int x^2 k(x)dx\neq0$. $k(\cdot)$ equals 0 outside a bounded interval, and $k(-x)=k(x)$ for any $x$.

Which kernel satisfy all the above requirement as well as $\int x^2 k(x)dx=1$?

Thanks!

Comment: So... you want a kernel with $E(X^p)=0$ for all $p<m$? So if $m=3$, the kernel has zero variance? That sounds like a Dirac $\delta$ function which isn't a very interesting or useful kernel (IMHO).

Comment: @kurtosis Thanks! You are right. Then I guess I want to focus on $m=2$.

Comment: Literally *every* continuous distribution with bounded support on the non-negative numbers corresponds to such a kernel. Letting $f$ be the pdf, defining $g(x)=f(|x|)/2$ gives a density with the first two properties you require (symmetric with zero expectation). Let $\sigma^2=\int x^2g(x)\mathrm{d}x$ be its variance. The function $k(x)=g(x\sigma)\sigma=\sigma f(|x\sigma|)/2$ satisfies all your requirements--and clearly you can recover $f$ from $k$ and $\sigma,$ showing how general this correspondence is. This result suggests the question isn't a fruitful one.  Could you explain the motivation?

Comment: @whuber Thanks! You are right. The motivation is that I read about this condition in a book and want to see how general it is.